# CrossFingerprint.Current.GetAuthenticationTypeAsync return invalid type

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In our xamarin forms application we are using Plugin.Fingerpint nuget package. we want to get the authentication type before proceeding to authentication. In android device only the issue is occurred. But in iOS its working fine. We have using the below code for getting the authentication type.

```
var AuthType = await CrossFingerprint.Current.GetAuthenticationTypeAsync();
if(AuthType == AuthenticationType.Face)
{ 

}
else if(AuthType == AuthenticationType.Fingerprint)
{

}
```

Please guide me to get the authentication type other than this procedure. The above mentioned issue is already in the issue list [Link](https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint/issues/188)

Comment: You have not described any actual problem with this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant code that affects this behavior is on this page: https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint/blob/master/src/Plugin.Fingerprint/Platforms/Android/FingerprintImplementation.cs

Looking at it I can see that that it can return just two values - either that the type is fingerprint or that authentication is not available.

So this is by design. And I would assume that Android cannot report this at the operating system level, so this works only on iOS.